# Query Google Spreadsheet Pivot Table through Google Sheets API

Tags: npm, google-sheets-api, google-apis-explorer

I have a Google Spreadsheet that uses a pivot table and I am trying to filter it and get data back from it.

[Google Sheet's API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#pivottable) lists PivotTables and the various classes you might be able to use to query, but it doesn't do a very a good job of covering pivot tables. So I am unsure how to query it.

I'm using npm's `googleapis` package and I have something like this:

```
sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
    auth: auth,
    spreadsheetId: SPREADSHEET_ID,
    range: "data!A:A0"
});
```

That's all I'm able to do. Adding other keys in the payload like "rows" or "columns" throws errors complaining that those keys aren't valid.

Has anyone been able to successfully query Sheets' API on a pivot table?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?  If you want to retrieve values, then the code you provided is the correct way to do it.  It doesn't matter if the sheet you're retrieving values from is a pivot table or a regular sheet.

You mention wanting to add "rows" or "columns" to the payload.  Why would you want to add those?  What would you expect them to do?

Comment: Oh, on second glance I think I understand what you're asking.

values.get takes the parameters listed on the [values.get docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get).

The PivotTable resource is returned by [Spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get), and used by some of the request methods of [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate), in [CellData](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#CellData)

Comment: But I don't see a PivotTable resource returned by Spreadsheet.get. That seem to be my issue then. Is it because I specified a range?

Comment: You can try to remove the range part, to verify if this is the cause of your problem. Just always use the available fields for PivotTable on the documentation to avoid any issue.

Comment: The code you posted isn't using spreadsheets.get, it's using spreadsheets.values.get.  The latter only returns cell values.  The former returns all properties of the spreadsheet.